# Extracting Data from XML With Same Name Tags using R language

Tags: r, data-manipulation

All Thanks In Advance,
I Was Trying to parse an XML file in R, But I got stuck up, I will explain what I got stuck in below.

There are several tag names specifically there is a tag called ID Segment Tag in which there will be multiple ID Name in which I have to extract the 2nd ID in the ID segment.
[XML1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdmVd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**sample data**

No sample data was given, so I crated my own.

```
library(xml2)
doc = read_xml('<?xml version="1.0" ?><ID><IDSegment><IDNumber>ABC1234BD</IDNumber><IDNumber>ABCDEFG</IDNumber></IDSegment></ID>')
```

**code**

```
#get all IDSegment_nodes
IDSegment.nodes <- xml_find_all( doc, ".//IDSegment")
#get the second IDNumber from each IDSegment-node.. NA if missing
xml_text( xml_find_first( IDSegment.nodes, ".//IDNumber[position() = 2]") )
```

**output**

> `[1] "ABCDEFG"`